# Foursquare api consumer disabled

Tags: php, api, foursquare

I recently started using the foursquare API, but suddenly I get "Consumer disabled" error responses.

So far, the only API call I've been doing is one to browse some venues:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=51.222816,3.224778&query=Friet&radius=200&limit=10&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259&client_id=app_id&client_secret=app_secret&v=20161116

These are the parameters I am sending:

```
ll:51.222816,3.224778
query:Friet
radius:200
limit:10
categoryId:4d4b7105d754a06374d81259
client_id:app_id
client_secret:app_secret
v:20161116
```

At first everything went well, then I started working on some other part and now I'm back to foursquare and getting the following response (with 403 http status code):

```
{
  "meta": {
    "code": 403,
    "errorType": "not_authorized",
    "errorDetail": "Consumer disabled."
  },
  "response": {}
}
```

I've searched my emails, but I didn't recieve any warnings or notifications on why this might be happening. Anyone had any experience with this?

One thing that may be of importance: Since I'm in development and there is no site for the project yet I can not provide a privacy policy url in the app settings. Because there is none, yet.

**Edit**: this is my client ID: 1VXNUT53J2OMMTMKA4E3UBKYLQQCI1GC3CRCCBPSQK1BWQFG

Comment: What's your client_id? (client_id is safe to share but DO NOT share client_secret)

Comment: I've added the client id to the question.

Answer (score 1):

try resetting your API secret at (https://foursquare.com/developers/app/CLIENT_ID/reset)

That error could happen if there's suspicious behavior on an API key - but you would've gotten an email first.

**Update:** I see this key flagged as `disabled`. I re-enabled so should be working now. I'll run through the logs and try to figure out how/why this happened.

Comment: Hm, that did not work. Even when resetting the secret I keep getting the same error. I created a new app and that one works, but I'm afraid it will stop working as well.
Also, I didn't receive any email.