# My working Foursquare api stopped working, failing consumer disabled

Tags: api, foursquare

I have been using the foursquare API, but suddenly I get "Consumer disabled" error responses.

The call I am making this to get venues will be look like `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=27.9253%2C-82.37368&client_id=HVVN3Q2GGRUDAQATCA2YE1H3E0KKYR0PGW15HRP0YIZNUW3G&client_secret={******}&mode=foursquare&v=20161223&query=Caw%20Residential%20Services& intent=browse&phone=8138466598&radius=1000`

I have the issue currently all my Api calls to foursquare venues are failing with

```
code":403,"errorType":"not_authorized","errorDetail":"Consumer disabled.
```

response.

my client id is

```
HVVN3Q2GGRUDAQATCA2YE1H3E0KKYR0PGW15HRP0YIZNUW3G
```

Comment: Have you already taken a look at your foursquare account to check everything is OK?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725074/foursquare-api-consumer-disabled

Comment: Yes everything looks good. I have also reset the app as well as per other post

Comment: I followed the above link to reset the app. but even that doesn't help. I have to create new app for this.....

Comment: In the above link I see **"Update: I see this key flagged as disabled. I re-enabled so should be working now. I'll run through the logs and try to figure out how/why this happened."**                                                             
     Is there a way we can re-enable the app? I don't see anywhere in developer site...

Comment: I'm having the same issue

Comment: I fixed the same issue after contact the support team.