# Foursquare can not recreate a personal account App after reset

Tags: python, web-crawler, foursquare, google-crawlers

I created an App as Personal Account in Foursquare. But it got `403` error response after I use search API for two days.

```
{
    u'meta': {
        u'errorType': u'not_authorized', 
        u'code': 403, 
        u'requestId': u'5b0905d21ed21925538f8d5a', 
        u'errorDetail': u'Consumer disabled.'
    }, 
    u'response': {}
}
```

I followed the method '[Foursquare api consumer disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725074/foursquare-api-consumer-disabled)', reset the `client_secret`, but it doesn't work. So I delete the App and want to recreate a new App. After I deleted the old App, I can't create a new personal app. The button is disabled. Only start-up and enterprise account work. Does anyone know why this happened and how to re-create an app as personal account again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foursquare api consumer disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725074/foursquare-api-consumer-disabled)

Comment: See also http://blog.koogawa.com/entry/2018/04/10/185225

Comment: those methods do not solve creating app problem.