# foursquare api return Consumer disabled

Tags: api, foursquare

We got problem when integrating foursquare api, when our user try to login by foursquare, it got error like

```
Array (
  [meta] => Array (
    [code] => 403
    [errorType] => not_authorized
    [errorDetail] => Consumer disabled.
    [requestId] => 5bcec530dd579757288953cb
  )
  [response] => Array ( )
)
```

Comment: fixed it by register a new account....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foursquare api consumer disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725074/foursquare-api-consumer-disabled)